# Error: Server returned HTTP code: 404

Tags: javascript, node.js, api

Bom dia pessoal estou tentando conectar a API do Google Earth Engine no meu servidor, porém estou me deparando com o seguinte erro.

> ```
> Error: Server returned HTTP code: 404
>     at Object.ee.data.handleResponse_ (C:\Users\EST\Desktop\express\node_modules\@google\earthengine\build\main.js:9843:9)
>     at Object.ee.data.send_ (C:\Users\EST\Desktop\express\node_modules\@google\earthengine\build\main.js:9792:18)
>     at Object.ee.data.getAlgorithms (C:\Users\EST\Desktop\express\node_modules\@google\earthengine\build\main.js:9465:24)
>     at Function.ee.ApiFunction.initialize (C:\Users\EST\Desktop\express\node_modules\@google\earthengine\build\main.js:10563:78)
>     at Object.ee.initialize (C:\Users\EST\Desktop\express\node_modules\@google\earthengine\build\main.js:12110:26)
>     at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\EST\Desktop\express\server.js:20:4)
>     at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:688:30)
>     at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:699:10)
>     at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:598:32)
>     at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:537:12)
> npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
> npm ERR! errno 1
> npm ERR! node-server-expres@1.0.0 start: `node server.js`
> npm ERR! Exit status 1
> npm ERR!
> npm ERR! Failed at the node-server-expres@1.0.0 start script.
> npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
> npm ERR!     C:\Users\EST\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2018-11-21T11_18_17_293Z-debug.log
> ```

Meu código:

```
const express = require('express')
const server = express()
const port = 8080

var ee = require('@google/earthengine');

// Authenticate using one (but not both) of the methods below.

ee.data.authenticateViaPrivateKey('./Georreferenciamento -dcbe3c4e1089.json');

ee.initialize();

// Run an Earth Engine script.
var image = new ee.Image('srtm90_v4');
image.getMap({min: 0, max: 1000}, function(map) {
  console.log(map);
});

server.listen(8080,()=>{
  console.log('servidor de pé em http://localhost:8080')
  console.log('Para desligar o servidor: ctrl + c')
})
```

Alguém pode me ajudar? Desde já agradeço

Comment: Segundo [este issue](https://github.com/google/earthengine-api/issues/45) isso se deve a um erro de autenticação do serviço.

Comment: seria com alguma autenticação direta com a google? Ou há algum erro no meu código fonte ?

Comment: Erro de autenticação do google mesmo, tem que verificar o acesso que você está fazendo pra ver se está correto. A biblioteca só está informando erroneamente 404 ao invés de 403

Comment: vou verificar, muito obrigado pela ajuda.